# What is this formula for sample standard deviation?

Tags: statistics

My textbook mentioned this formula without any explanation:

s<sub>x</sub> = $\sqrt{\frac{{∑fm}^2}{n} − \bar{x}^2}$ 
where
s<sub>x</sub> = sample standard deviation
$\bar{x}$ = sample mean

I thought the sample standard deviation was:
s = $\sqrt{\frac{∑(x − \bar{x})^2}{n - 1} }$?

Comment: Note that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - n\bar{x}^2$. (You can show this using algebra.) Using this fact, you can show that the textbook is using $\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n}}$. (I'm assuming your $\sum fm2$ means $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2$.) So they are using a denominator of $n$ rather than $n-1$ for some reason.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth answer is correct. The reason of the $n$ versus $n-1$ in the denominator correspond to the [Bessel’s correction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) for the standard deviation estimator.

Comment: So that means the textbook was wrong because they used n instead of n - 1?

Comment: Not wrong, per se, but imprecise about terminology.